# How to verify if an element is disabled using protrator

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor, automated-tests

I tried with below methods

1) using isEnabled api

```
expect(locator.isEnabled()).toEqual('false');
```

but it fails, as the API always returns true.

2) using disabled attribute

```
expect(locator.getAttribute('disabled')).toEqual('disabled');
```

but it fails, as the API returns null

Comment: please share the html code for that element?

Comment: In your html what is the code? Is it just the attribute name like: <foo disabled> Or is it given a value: <foo disabled="disabled">? If so, what would getAttribute('disabled') give you in the console.log?

Comment: [issuelink](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/577)  - Here you can find some solutions.

Comment: @rrd please find the html code <input type="checkbox" ng-model="event.exclusiveFlag" ng-init="" ng-change="" ng-disabled="updation" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" disabled="disabled">

Comment: As written in the question it returns null

Answer (score 0):

The disabled attribute is of type boolean so will return true or false.

isEnabled schedules a command to query whether the DOM element represented by this instance is enabled, as dicted by the disabled attribute.

Therefore in your situation the following assertion should be used when using isEnabled:

`expect(locator.isEnabled()).toBe(false);`

getAttribute schedules a command to query for the value of the given attribute of the element. It will return the current value. getAttribute returns a string and as the disabled attribute is considered a boolean, it will return 'true' of type string or null.

When using getAttribute you should use the following assertion:

`expect(locator.getAttribute('disabled')).toEqual('true');`

Comment: Thanks for you're reply. The assertions in the question and answer are certainly NOT the same. I'd suggest you learn more about Javascript data types and strict equality comparison.

Answer (score 0):

As I learned, there are two ways to archive element disable in web development.

**1)** use `disabled` attribute, only work on **Form Control** element

**Note:** If a Form Control element defined `disabled` attribute, no matter the attribute value is 'disabled', 'true', 'false', '1234' or anything else. Selenium isEnabled() will always return true.
In such case you can use: `expect(locator.isEnabled()).toEqual()`

**2)** use CSS & JavaScript, work on any HTML element

**Note:** In most time, using CSS & JavaScript way to archive disable goal, developer will add class name like: 'invalid', 'disable', 'ng-invalid' in element attribute `class`. 
In such case, you can use: `expect(locator.getAttribute('class')).toContain('xxx')`

You need to find out which way developer used on the element before you can decide how to write script to check it.